# Nested list comprehension / merging nested lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a problem understanding a nested list comprehension structure.

I have a list

```
>>> test
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

If I do

```
t2=[]
for x in test:
    for y in x:
        t2.append(y)
```

then it returns

```
>>> t2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

which is exactly what I want. But WHY can't I do

```
t3=[y for y in x for x in test]
```

This gives me

```
>>> t3
[6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8]
```

Can anybody explain to me why t3 is not the same as t2? How ca I write a list comprehension expression that gives me the same as t2? Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for ... in ...` clauses inside a list comprehension need to go in the same order as if they were normal for-loops:

```
>>> test = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
>>> t3 = [y for x in test for y in x]
>>> t3
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, before starting, `x = [6, 7, 8]` from your previous loop (as pointed out by jonsharpe).

Therefore, it unfolds as such:

```
for y in x:
    for x in test:
        t3.append(y)
```

`x` in the first loop point to `[6, 7, 8]`, and is later reassigned, but that does not change the reference that is used in the first loop. The result would be the same if the second `x` had a distinct name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse the `for` loops:

```
t3 = [y for x in test for y in x]
```

otherwise (if you don't run the multi-line version beforehand!) `x` is undefined. Your code only ran on a fluke - `x` was still what it was at the end of the previous `for` loop, hence your results.

Answer (score 0):

Just making sure you know about [itertools chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
>>> test=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain(*test))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```